# Recursive confusion within an if condition, how is JS interpreting the "truthly/falsely" condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

In the following recursive code snippet:

```
function addArray(total,array){
  total += array[0];
  remainingList = array.slice(1);

  if (remainingList > 0){
    console.log(remainingList);
    return addArray(total,remainingList);
  }
  else {
    return total;
  }
}
```

Then at the console:

*array option - 1*

> scores = [1,2,3];
>   totalScores = addArray(0,scores);  // 1 - ???

< 1

*array option - 2*

> scores = [1,2];
>   totalScores = addArray(0,scores);  // 3 - makes sense

*[2]*

< 3

*array option - 3*

> scores = [2,3,4];
>   totalScores = addArray(0,scores); // 2 - ???

< 2

*array option - 4*

> scores = [2,3];
>   totalScores = addArray(0,scores); // 5 - makes sense

*[3]*

> 5

*array option - 5*

> scores = [1,2,3,4];
>   totalScores = addArray(0,scores); // 1 - ???

< 1

I can easily fix by using  "if (remainingList.length > 0)..."  in the code snippet, but I am trying to figure out whats actually going on with just using the array in the if condition. How is Javascript interpreting the "truthly" / "falsely" outcomes given the different array options.  I know that an empty array [ ] = true, but I can't seem to be clear on how the function exits from using the different array options.

Comment: In this line `remainingList = array.slice(1);`, `remainingList` is an array. So you're comparing an array to a scalar. I don't think this is what you want...

Comment: Yes - this put my understanding on the right track.

Comment: Please remember to accept your favourite answer, so SO can properly retire the question.  You have an explanation and a repair in the posted answers; you could also post a combined answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes when you compare an array to the constant scalar **0**.  This happens when you have at least 3 elements in the list.  This comparison is *false*, and the routine returns with the sum it computed on the first element alone.

With 1 element, you get the remaining list as null, returning the value of the first element.  With 2 elements, the one-element tail evaluates the way the algorithm would want, and you return the sum of the two elements.

Comment: This clears things up completely.  When there are 3 or more elements in the originating array, a "false" decision to (remainingList > 0) occurs since the code compares the sliced remaining array to a scalar, but the subtle difference (where my confusion was created) is when just having 2 elements to start with in the array.  The 1st recursive call leaves a one-element tail that evaluates the way I am expecting and the sum of the 2 elements is returned.  Very clear and concise explanation -  Tks

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended to write `if (remainingList.length > 0)`, rather than `if (remainingList > 0)`. Note that the latter compares an array to a single value, which doesn't really make sense.

```
function addArray(total,array){
  total += array[0];
  remainingList = array.slice(1);

  if (remainingList.length > 0){
    console.log(remainingList);
    return addArray(total,remainingList);
  }
  else {
    return total;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think he is asking how 'if (remainingList > 0)' works, he understands that it is wrong.

Comment: Correct: check the last paragraph of the original post.

Comment: Definitely true... + that's the problem